# Add authentications to couchbase REST API endpoints?

Tags: couchbase

I’m using community edition of couchbase version , when i hit the apis http://<server_name>:8091/versions or http://<server_name>:8092 , it gives me the version of the software installed with few other information. Is there any way to restrict those apis or implement authentication for the same.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a Couchbase-specific feature to block these, but there may be a way to block access to certain URLs at the firewall or network level. Might be a better question for https://security.stackexchange.com/